# Atzeret to gather or store?

Tags: sources-mekorot, commentaries, translation, shmini-atzeres, samson-raphael-hirsch

Atzeret (עצרת) comes from the root עצר which means (nifal, as a verb) to stop, be delayed or to be arrested.

But I also heard that R.S.Hirsch explains it means 'to collect, to store or to gather' as in the root עוצר

But I can't find the source for this, so I would like to ask if anyone knows the right source or any other commentary which explains it as such.

Answer (score 2):

There is a discussion in *gemara* if one substitutes, as proposal, the words "you are עצורתי". Rashi interprets this to mean (BT [Kid. 6a, s.v. עצורתי](https://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9F_%D7%95_%D7%90)):

> לשון עצרת שתהא נאספת עמי לבית

This would mean "gather", as in be stored together with the husband in a home.